# How to set value in MySQL(5.6) column if that contains json document as string

Tags: mysql, json

How to set value in MySQL(5.6) column if that contains JSON document as a string

For example, if we have a table - user in that we have three columns id, name and jsonConfig and column jsonConfig contains data as a JSON document

`{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3"}`

I would like to replace the value of `val1` let's say to `val4` for jsonConfig column

Can we do that using MySQL(5.6) queries?

Comment: Store it as a string and handle that string accordingly.

Comment: Well if the database doesn't handle that function you have two options. Write an extension for your version of MySQL or (don't know what language you will be using for your program but) soething like `jQuery.parseJSON(stringOffYourDB)`. Hint, the latter is far, far less of a ballache.

Comment: Ok. Your version of MySQL doesn't support what you are trying to do. So as you are rude, you don't deserve anything further. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing their is direct way to do this like in later version alot of json support was added like `JSON_EXTRACT`, `JSON_CONTAINS` etc.You might have to write your own custom function.

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL 5.6, since it does not have the JSON data type or the supporting functions, you are going to have to replace the entire string via an UPDATE query if you want to change any part of the JSON document in your string.